# Can text that isn't printed but exists in the source code be extraced somehow?

Tags: pdf, sourcecode

I'm using the exam class to create exams and tests etc.

The class has environments for including the solutions to problems and allow you to choose to have those solutions printed after the question. My plan is to create two pdfs, one without the solutions for the students, and one for the graders with the solutions.

What I want to know is if a techsavvy students might be able to extract the solutions from the pdf, when they aren't being exported to pdf. Is it necessary for me to create another .tex file that has the solutions, or is that not needed?

Comment: I am not familiar with the `exam` class but as long as it doesn't embed the source code into the pdf (which I doubt) there should be no risk.

Comment: You could try by yourself. Compile your code to a PDF then make a search for the *unprinted* text inside the PDF code. It should not be there.

Comment: you didn't provide an example to test, but imho it uses spaces to reserve the place and so doesn't include the solutions in the pdf.

Comment: No, the hidden answer is not sent to the PDF at all.   (It's not \special ;-)

Comment: You might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482459/dynamic-spacing-in-exam-package intereesting.