# Comment out some lines but retain the spacing they would have created had they been included in document

Tags: conditionals, comments

Consider:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{comment}
% \includecomment{answer} %show answers
\excludecomment{answer} % do not show answers

\begin{document}

Question 1: How many hours are in a day?

\begin{answer}

There are 24 hours in a day.

\end{answer}

Question 2: How many minutes are in an hour?

\begin{answer}

There are 60 minutes in an hour.

\end{answer}

\end{document}
```

Depending on which of the two lines:

```
\includecomment{answer} %show answers
\excludecomment{answer} % do not show answers
```

are part of the document and which are commented out, the answer lines are displayed or not displayed.

Is it possible, in case `\excludecomment{answer}` is active, to retain the spacing between the question lines? The amount of spacing should be the spacing that would exist between the question lines *had the answers been included*. As of now, when answers are excluded, there is no spacing between the questions.

The idea is to create documents with spacing between questions so that students can, in class, fill in the space by pen/pencil, while I retain the typeset answers.

If the `comment` package cannot accomplish this, any other alternative to retain the spacing would also be useful.

Comment: You should look at exam class, although it requires you to estimate the needed space (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482459/dynamic-spacing-in-exam-package).  Other alternatives use the opacity package or lrbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty (makes the hypothesis that you do not want to use fancy colors in you document).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx}
\newcommand{\answer}{\color{white}}
\newcommand{\question}{\color{black}}
\begin{document}

\question

Question 1: How many hours are in a day?

\answer

There are 24 hours in a day.

\question

Question 2: How many minutes are in an hour?

\answer

There are 60 minutes in an hour.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, that is quite clever. So, in my version, I make answer also of black font, while in the students' version, I keep it white? That is quite neat, I must say.

Comment: @Tryer You are welcome. Please condider accepting the answer if this suits you.

Comment: I am curious to know if this is capable of respecting within answer a `\begin{proof}`statement? i.e., will a proof of a proposition be hidden this way as well? Let me test it out for its robustness. Perhaps there should be a `\begin{answer} ... \end{answer}` type idiom here?

Comment: @Tryer You may want to use `\newenvironment{answer}{\color{white}}{}` and `\newenvironment{question}{\color{black}}{}` instead of `\newcommand`. Should be more robust.

Answer (score 2):

This create a new answer environment using lrbox and a minipage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\newif\ifshowanswers
\newsavebox{\answerbox}
\newenvironment{answer}{\par%\noindent
  \begin{lrbox}{\answerbox}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \linewidth-\parindent}}% body
{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \ifshowanswers
    \usebox\answerbox\par
  \else
    \vskip\ht\answerbox
    \vskip\dp\answerbox
  \fi}
  
\showanswerstrue
%\showanswersfalse

\begin{document}

Question 1: How many hours are in a day?

\begin{answer}

There are 24 hours in a day.

\end{answer}

Question 2: How many minutes are in an hour?

\begin{answer}

There are 60 minutes in an hour.

\end{answer}

\end{document}
```