# Improving my answerbox code for the exam class

Tags: tikz-pgf, exam

I am using the exam class for my work, and I have found that structuring the space where students fill in their answers can significantly speed up the grading process. To achieve this, I created a new command called `\answerbox`, which generates designated spaces for student responses. Here is the code I implemented for this purpose:

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% Command for small answer Box
% \answerbox{length}{height}{solution}
% solution is only printed if answers is a class option
% solution argument must not be an environment
% tikz can still be added with \tikz{...}
\newcommand{\answerbox}[3]{%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\halfheight}{0.5*#2cm}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\halfwidth}{0.5*#1cm}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\adjustheight}{-0.45*#2cm}
    \ifprintanswers
        \raisebox{\adjustheight}{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw (0, 0) rectangle (#1cm, #2cm);
                \node at (\halfwidth, \halfheight) {\color{red!75!black}\large\textbf{#3}};
            \end{tikzpicture}%
        }%
    \else
        \raisebox{\adjustheight}{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw (0, 0) rectangle (#1cm, #2cm);
            \end{tikzpicture}%
        }%
    \fi
}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question
    \answerbox{3.25}{4}{$\begin{bmatrix}
            0.25\\0.25\\0.25\\0.25
        \end{bmatrix}$}
    
    \answerbox{4}{2}{Richard Feynman}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I want to expand upon this code snippet and make it more robust. I've done some initial assessment, but I want to be thorough to avoid any future problems, that may cause a lot of work for me/others. I was hoping you could assist me in enhancing it further. If you spot any potential issues or have any insightful suggestions, I'd be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 1):

This shows a `\framebox` solution.  The default alignment is the baseline of the contents.  `\raisebox` aligns the top.

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% Command for small answer Box
% \answerbox{length}{height}{solution}
% solution is only printed if answers is a class option
% solution argument must not be an environment
% tikz can still be added with \tikz{...}
\newcommand{\answerbox}[3]{% #1 = width, #2 = height, #3 = contents
\bgroup% make changes local
    \ifprintanswers
      \sbox0{\color{red!75!black}\large\textbf{#3}}% measure contents
      \setlength{\fboxsep}{\dimexpr #2cm /2 - 0.5\ht0 - 0.5\dp0}%
      \raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\height}{\framebox[#1cm]{\usebox0}}%
    \else
      \setlength{\fboxsep}{\dimexpr #2cm /2 - 0.5\baselineskip}%
      \raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\height}{\framebox[#1cm]{\strut}}%
    \fi
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question
    \answerbox{3.25}{4}{$\begin{bmatrix}
            0.25\\0.25\\0.25\\0.25
        \end{bmatrix}$}
    
    \answerbox{4}{2}{Richard Feynman}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

---

This centers an answer in a solutionbox.

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\answerbox}[2]{% #1 = height, #2 = contents
  \begin{solutionbox}{#1cm}
    \sbox0{\color{red!75!black}\large\textbf{#2}}% measure contents
    \strut\par\vskip-\parskip\vskip-\baselineskip\centering
    \raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5\dp0-0.5\ht0}[\dimexpr #1cm /2 - 3\fboxsep]%
      [\dimexpr #1cm /2 - 3\fboxsep]{\usebox0}
\end{solutionbox}}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question show a column vector.
    
    \answerbox{4}{$\begin{bmatrix}
            0.25\\0.25\\0.25\\0.25
        \end{bmatrix}$}
    
    \question Who is buried in Richard Feynman's tomb?
    
    \answerbox{2}{Richard Feynman}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What are the pros of your solution compared to my initial approach? Can you shortly explain it, so that I may learn something new? :D

Comment: What is your opinion on the parameter? Does it "fit" into the exam class, is something missing?

Comment: Simplicity, both in coding and execution.  `\fbox` and `\framebox` are standard LaTeX and use parameters `\fboxrule` (line width) and `\fboxsep` (margin).  `\framebox` allows you to specify the width.  OTOH, I see no real advantage of this over `\solutionbox` (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482459/dynamic-spacing-in-exam-package)/

Comment: Actually, trying to center an answer inside a solutionbox is harder than I expected, mostly due to its own margins/  Also, leaving off the units is not LaTeX style.  TikZ does it for coordinates, but not for arguments, and the unit is not neccessarily 1cm.

Comment: Yeah while playing around with your solution, I saw that there are some alignment problems. But giving width and height is important, because for some exercises, e.g. a cloze, I need a small height but a long width. Do you know a solution for that?

Comment: On the other hand: Your solution allows environments as arguments, which my approach can not handle. That could be very useful!

Comment: You can't put a tikzpicture inside a tikzpicture, but you can put a tikzpicture inside a savebox, then put the savebox inside a tikzpicture.

Comment: Can you also create your alternative solution with a parameter for the length, in the case no solution should be printed. The empty box is for the students to fill in their answers, and they need more space than the computer generated text.

Comment: I thought the reason for centering the answer in given space was to use the same space both times (consistent layout).  BTW, which solution: the framebox or solutionbox?